# Opening URL in browser by clicking button

Tags: objective-c, ios7, hyperlink, title

Hi friends,
I am getting data from server when user post a link on his timeline am displaying like this but my requirement is when i click Title then it will open browser. How can i do this?

[image: when i click **Bollywood.com:Entertainment news,movie,music and fashion rev**]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]];
```

Will open a URL by the Application defined for the scheme. http has Safari as default (I guess)

To open it in the App itself create a ViewController + xib, 
add a UIWebView to your View 
& Buttons to get back to the app.

Then you can create an instance of your new ViewController and present it with

```
[self presentViewController:WebVC animated:YES completion:^(void){
    [[WebVC MyWebView] loadRequest: [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
}];
```

e.g.

To make it even easier you could add a function to your ViewController like this one

```
-(void) LoadUrlFromString: (NSString *)url{
[self.MyWebView loadRequest: [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]]];
}
```

and then just do as before but call

```
[WebVC LoadUrlFromString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
```

on completition

Comment: i knw about this but major problem is safari will open then safari doesn't have back button...if you have iphone then you can see new version of facebook in that link will be open having with back option..

Comment: The New Facebook app uses a WebView not "safari" itself.

Comment: oh ok...then how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TTTAttributedlabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

```
 TTTAttributedlabel *title_lbl = [TTTAttributedlabel alloc]init] //Make it an instance of TTTAttributed label what you are using for displaying the Title.

 NSRange range = [title_lbl.text rangeOfString:"YOUR_TILE_HERE (Latest bollywod and hollywood.....")"];
 [title_lbl addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL_HERE (www.bollywood.com)"] withRange:range];
 title_lbl.delegate = self;
```

And for onlcick method

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
  NSlog("%@",label.text);
  [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: When user tap on the title_lbl this method will be called  it defined in TTTAttributedLabelDelegate.  Delegate implementors would have to adopt this protocol and implement the method -(void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url.

Comment: ....my code.... 
        TTTAttributedLabel *title_lbl = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc]init] ;
        title_lbl.frame=CGRectMake(14, 280, 270, 100);
        NSRange range = [title_lbl.text rangeOfString:linkTitle];
        [title_lbl addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkUrl] withRange:range];
        title_lbl.delegate = self;
        [cell2 addSubview:title_lbl];

Comment: - (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
     NSLog(@"%@",label.text);
    LinkOpenWebViewController *linkView = [[LinkOpenWebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LinkOpenWebViewController" bundle:nil];
    [ [linkView webViewToOpenLink] loadRequest: [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkUrl]]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:linkView animated:YES];
}

Comment: if i click on title_lbl then it will be open my webview controller with url

Comment: Are u setting the Text on title_lbl e.g. title.lbl.text = @"Latest bollywod and hollywood....."?

Comment: is the delegate set in your .h file ? Also if this is the approach you are comfortable with, you can use NSAttributedString to achieve the same effect instead of TTTAttributedLabel.